# Run Tensorflow unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, tensorflow, testing, bazel

Is there any way to run Tensorflow unit tests manually? I want to perform sanity checks while modifying TF source code.

I see there are many _test.py files with classes that perform many test operations and I can't figure out how to run them. There should be an easy way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The easiest way to run the TensorFlow unit tests is using Bazel, assuming you have [downloaded the source from Git](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#source):

```
# All tests (for C++ changes).
$ bazel test //tensorflow/...

# All Python tests (for Python front-end changes).
$ bazel test //tensorflow/python/...

# All tests (with GPU support).
$ bazel test -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/...
$ bazel test -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/python/...
```

Comment: And how would you run these tests with gpu support? Just directly executing them only seems to use CPU: `I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:40] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 16
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:58] Direct session inter op parallelism threads: 16
`

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to build and run with GPU support. (Note that those log messages will be produced in CPU *and* GPU modes.)

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to emphasize that only the CPU is listed right now. Thanks for your update!

Comment: Thank you ! How to run a single one ? For example , array_ops_test.cc

Comment: `bazel test //tensorflow/core:ops_array_ops_test`

Comment: How to run it under gdb?

Comment: Do we need `--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"` for `bazel test` options?

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the above answer, you can run individual tests as shown instead of full packages, which can save a significant amount of time.

```
bazel run //tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:string_split_op_test

bazel run //tensorflow/python:special_math_ops_test
```

Or you can go to the individual directory and run all the tests there

```
cd python/kernel_tests
bazel run :one_hot_op_test
```

Comment: What about GPU support options when we run bazel ?