# Debug tensorflow unit tests

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, gdb, tensorflow

I find the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204551/run-tensorflow-unit-tests) which shows how to run the unit tests.

And I think it could get a better understanding about the source code by debug the unit tests.

I can debug the source code as the tensorflow python application run. But I don't know how to debug the unit test. I am new to bazel and gdb debug.

Comment: Each "bazel test" essentially runs a corresponding binary under `bazel-bin` so you can run that binary directly, under gdb

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thank you , but I can't find the position of the test file . For example , common_shape_fns_test.cc , I search the `common_shape_fns_test.cc` string and find it in the BUILD file . Then I can't find any hint.

Comment: Now I know I should build it first :                                                            `bazel build //tensorflow/core:framework_common_shape_fns_test` .     Then I can run it :
`bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/framework_common_shape_fns_test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize:

- you have to make sure the test binary is built first: either by running `bazel test <target>` or with `bazel build <target>` or with `bazel build -c dbg <target>`. The last one gives fully debuggable executables that give you line numbers in gdb backtrace.
- The binary is in the same directory as the BUILD file (ie, if you have `tensorflow/core/BUILD`, then the binary will be under `bazel-bin/tensorflow/core`)
- You can find the name of bazel  that includes given `.cc` file by using bazel query. IE, for `common_shape_fns_test` you can find that target name is `//tensorflow/core:framework_common_shape_fns_test` by using command below

.

```
fullname=$(bazel query tensorflow/core/framework/common_shape_fns_test.cc)
bazel query "attr('srcs', $fullname, ${fullname//:*/}:*)"
```