# Issues with building tensorflow unit tests

Tags: tensorflow, build, googletest, position-independent-code

I need to run tests on some XLA passes and used `bazel test 
 --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/compiler/xla/service` to do the same (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204551/run-tensorflow-unit-tests)). The build failed with the following message, hinting at the missing googletest dependency.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

The dependences `libgtest.a` and `libgtest_main.a` were built from the googletest source and passed to the linker using `--linkopt=/path/to/file`.

```
googletest/googletest/libgtest_main.a(gtest_main.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC` didn't help. How can I change the cmake config to build with -fPIC ?

tensorflow (v1.8) is configured to be built by a locally built version gcc (5.4), since the system's version (5.5) fails to build tensorflow. Would that be the cause of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Linking to the shared libraries instead of the object file archive solved this problem, i.e.,

```
bazel test --linkopt="$GTEST_DIR/libgtest.so" --linkopt="GTEST_DIR/libgtest_main.so"
```

instead of,

```
bazel test --linkopt="$GTEST_DIR/libgtest.a" --linkopt="GTEST_DIR/libgtest_main.a"
```

This still doesn't help run tensorflow unit tests. There are build errors in dependences of the unit tests, eg. the compilation of `//tensorflow/...../absl/base/internal` fails.