# Run Tensorflow Unit Test with IDE

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

Following upon the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204551/run-tensorflow-unit-tests), what is the best practice way to run tensorflow unit tests using IDE like CLion? For example, running TEST_F from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/constant_folding_test.cc).

Assuming that the tensorflow is built from source using Bazel. How do you integrate the build with any IDE?