# Running selected TensorFlow test with bazel

Tags: tensorflow, googletest, bazel

I'd like to run selected tests from Tensor Flow unit tests using bazel, but I cannot get good enough granularity.

For example I am interested in running test `SessionClusterSpecPropagationTest.testFullDeviceNames` from `//tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph_py_test`

I figured out so far I can run `bazel test -c opt //tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph_py_test`, but unfortunately, this is running all of the tests from this gtest.

Regular `--gtest_filter` is not working. I also tried `--test_filter=SessionClusterSpecPropagationTest.testFullDeviceNames`, but I couldn't run single test either.

Could someone please recommend how to run it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py) for Tensorflow test cases. This are the [best practises](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/contribute/tests). You should try running **bazel test** for executing the test cases.

```
# All tests (for C++ changes).
$ bazel test //tensorflow/...

# All Python tests (for Python front-end changes).
$ bazel test //tensorflow/python/...

# All tests (with GPU support).
$ bazel test -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/...
$ bazel test -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/python/...
```

For more reference : [Run Tensorflow unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204551/run-tensorflow-unit-tests)