# how to install tensorflow for windows 7 32bit system?i installed python 3.5(32 bit) into my system and also installed anaconda 3.4.4(32 bit)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

i have only 32bit system so i installed python 3.5 (64 bit ) error occurs .so i installed python 32bit successfully after that i followed by that document(http://tensorflow.org/install/…) i tried this into command prompt

```
C:\Users\mydoc>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

but error occurs like this.

```
C:\Users\mydoc>pip install tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

C:\Users\mydoc>
```

please help me how to install tensorflow for my windows (32-bit)system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question is already answered:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634525/tensorflow-on-32-bit-linux)

> We have only tested the TensorFlow distribution on 64-bit Linux and
>   Mac OS X, and distribute binary packages for those platforms only. Try
>   following the [source installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/#installing_from_sources) to build a version
>   for your platform.
>   **EDIT**: One user has published [instructions for running TensorFlow on a 32-bit ARM processor](http://cudamusing.blogspot.in/2015/11/building-tensorflow-for-jetson-tk1.html?m=1) , which is promising for other 32-bit
>   architectures. These instructions may have useful pointers for getting
>   TensorFlow and Bazel to work in a 32-bit environment.

Comment: This question is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634525/tensorflow-on-32-bit-linux

Comment: OP is on 32-bit Windows, not Linux

Comment: But it doesnot works on windows7 32bit..Is there any way to install into it?

Comment: This is a wrong answer. That question was for Linux-32bit and not windows. It is *way* harder on windows.

Answer (score 4):

If using TensorFlow is not a hard requirement, you can consider changing back-ends for Keras. You will be able to use Theano as a back end, which has support for 32-bit windows. Find instructions for that here: https://keras.io/backend/
I understand that this may not answer your question, but changing back-ends may be easier than changing computers.

Comment: This is probably what I am going to do. I wanted to use tensorflow but I guess keras also works for deep learning the same way. +1! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## How to install Tensorflow in a 32 bits linux system

Following is a copy of the step list that I maintain in this github repository: [tensorflow-32-bits-linux](https://github.com/jahnog/tensorflow-32-bits-linux)

I used the following steps to install tensorflow in a old Asus Eee-Pc 1000H. Granted, it has been upgraded from the original 1 GB of RAM and an 80 GB HDD, to 2 GB of RAM and to 480 GB of SSD storage, that runs Ubuntu Xenial 32 bits without problems.

I also has been able to install it in a Debian 9 (stretch) 32 bits system, and the instructions are the same.

### Choose a convenient linux system

I have tested both the Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and Debian 9.11 (Stretch) systems with 2 GB of RAM.

I set up the system to have 4 GB of SWAP space. With only 1 GB of SWAP, some compilations failed.

It's critical that the distribution has the version 8 of the Java SDK: openjdk-8-jdk

### Install the Java 8 SDK and build tools

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt-get install git zip unzip autoconf automake libtool curl zlib1g-dev swig build-essential
```

### Install Python libraries

Next, we install python 3 development libraries and the keras module that will be required by tensorflow.

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip python3-wheel
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --user keras
```

You can use eithr python 3 or python 2 and compile tensorflow for that version.

### Install and compile Bazel from sources

We need the source code bazel 0.19.2 distribution. We can obtain it and install in a new folder.

```sh
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.19.2/bazel-0.19.2-dist.zip
mkdir Bazel-0-19.2
cd Bazel-0-19.2
unzip ../bazel-0.19.2-dist.zip
```

Before compiling, we need to remove line 30 of ./src/tools/singlejar/mapped_file_posix.inc file (**#error This code for 64 bit Unix.**) that throws an error if we are not in a 64 bit machine. This bazel version works ok in 32 bits.

Also we need to increase the java memory available to Bazel and start compiling it.

```sh
export BAZEL_JAVAC_OPTS="-J-Xmx1g"
./compile.sh
```

When it finishes (It can take several hours), we move the bazel compiled executable to some location in the current user's path

```sh
cp output/bazel /home/user/.local/bin
```

### Compile Tensorflow from sources

Create a folder and clone tensorflow's 1.13.2 version to it. Starting from version 1.14, tensorflow uses the Intel MKL DNN optimization library that it only works in 64 bits systems. So 1.13.2 is the last version that runs in 32 bits.

```sh
mkdir Tensorflow-1.13.2
cd Tensorflow-1.13.2
git clone -b v1.13.2 --depth=1 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow .
```

Before compiling, we replace the references to 64 bit libraries to the 32 bit ones.

```sh
grep -Rl "lib64"| xargs sed -i 's/lib64/lib/g'
```

We start the tensorflow configuration. We need to explicity disable the use of several optional libraries that are not available or not supported on 32 bit systems.

```sh
export TF_NEED_CUDA=0
export TF_NEED_AWS=0
./configure
```

We have to take the following considerations:
* When asked to specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: We should respond **/usr/bin/python3** to use python 3.
* When asked to input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages] we just hit **Enter**
* We should respond **N** to all the Y/N questions.
* When asked to specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native -Wno-sign-compare]: Just hit **Enter**

Now we start compiling tensorflow disabling optional components like aws, kafka, etc.

```sh
bazel build --config=noaws --config=nohdfs --config=nokafka --config=noignite --config=nonccl -c opt --verbose_failures //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

If everything went ok, now we generate the pip package.

```sh
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

And we install the pip package

```sh
python3 -m pip install --user /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.13.2-cp35-cp35m-linux_i686.whl
```

### Test tensorflow

Now we run a small test to check that it works. We create a test.py file with the following contents:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

And we run the test

```sh
python3 test.py
```

Here is the output

```sh
Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 87s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.2202 - acc: 0.9348
Epoch 2/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 131s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0963 - acc: 0.9703
Epoch 3/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 135s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0685 - acc: 0.9785
Epoch 4/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 128s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0526 - acc: 0.9828
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 128s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0436 - acc: 0.9863
10000/10000 [==============================] - 3s 273us/sample - loss: 0.0666 - acc: 0.9800
```

Enjoy you new Tensorflow !!