# Error when importing tensorflow; says several modules are missing

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow in Windows 7 (32 bit) with Anaconda according to the instructions given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). But when trying to import tensorflow, I get the following error:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\h473>python
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr  7 2018, 04:53:16) [MSC v.1900 32 bi
t (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_imp
ort_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [
dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.
py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>

    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_imp
ort_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_imp
ort_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [
dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.
py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>

    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\h473\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site
-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_imp
ort_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

I also tried installing it like so:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

But this did not even install tensorflow; it gives the following error:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Please suggest what's the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: can you add traceback of `pip install tensorflow`? What error is this showing?

Comment: @harshil9968 edited the question details at the end to include the exact error.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/diarabit/17d9051f9505c9d554d8a7d0c2bc4eb1, try running this script on your system

Comment: @harshil9968 It gives the same error, "ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.", and also points out that tensorflow-gpu files are missing, but I don't want tensorflow-gpu, I want tensorflow with only CPU.

Comment: upgrade your pip too, download **get-pip.py** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: @harshil9968 done already; performed all the steps mentioned in the forums related to this problem. Could the problem be arising due to the 32 bit Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the questions posted on Tensorflow installation page under **Common Installation Problems** section, maybe you can try the solutions provided in the linked SO question.

As for pip installation not working, maybe you should try: `python -m pip install tensorflow`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Performed all the solutions proposed in this forum, the error persists.

Comment: Might be an issue with 32-bit architecture, as this question shows [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449972/how-to-install-tensorflow-for-windows-7-32bit-systemi-installed-python-3-532-b).

Comment: You might check out this post about setting up tensorflow on a 32-bit ARM architecture [blog](http://cudamusing.blogspot.in/2015/11/building-tensorflow-for-jetson-tk1.html)