# Tensorflow on 32-bit Windows 10: is not a supported wheel on this platform; package missing in current win-32 channels, no matching distribution

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, installation, 32-bit

I have been following the installation guide from http://machinelearningmastery.com/setup-python-environment-machine-learning-deep-learning-anaconda/

I got & am using:

```
conda 4.3.22
Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (32-bit)

scipy: 0.19.0
numpy: 1.12.1
matplotlib: 2.0.2
pandas: 0.20.1
statsmodels: 0.8.0
sklearn: 0.18.2
```

I successfully installed theano & keras. HOWEVER, I FAIL at installing tensorflow. Please HELP.

I created a conda ‘tensorflow’ environment with python 3.5. With command

```
『pip install –ignore-installed –upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl』
```

I got ERROR saying

> 『tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform』

So i changed to version 1.0.1 and same error.
Version 1.1.0 also same error.

So i deactivated the environment, and type command

```
『conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow』
```

I got ERROR

> 『PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-32 channels』

Instead it says the close match found is “xtensor” which i know is a C++ library that I'm not looking for.

Is it because I’m using a 32-bit Windows 10?

So I also tried running the following :

```
『python -m pip install –upgrade tensorflow』
```

and got ERROR of

> 『Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow』

What more requirements do i need for this?

I tried `『pip3 install tensorflow』` but somehow it could not recognized ‘pip3’. So i type 『where pip3』 and it could not find files for the given pattern. So i type`『where python』`. It ouput the directory of my python. Then checked if it’s already put under the path inside the environmental variable. And it has. But i still couldn't use pip3 command.

I have tried all the solutions provided from people having similar problem with me and none of them work.

Comment: What's with all the `『` symbols? Just surround your commands and code with backticks, like this: `\`I am some code\``. You post will be a lot more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634525/tensorflow-on-32-bit-linux).

In short, yes, TensorFlow does not support 32-bit platforms. Although if you only plan on writing abstract high-level Keras code then Theano will do just fine.