# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fancyimpute' when importing MICE package to deal with missing values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, fancyimpute

I am trying to import the `fancyimpute` package for imputation in dealing with missing values. However, the above error occurred when I try to do so. I tried running `pip3 install fancyimpute` in cmd but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from fancyimpute) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow (from fancyimpute)
```

I tried to upgrade pip but it seems it is already upgraded. I am not sure whether is it because the package `tensorflow` is not being installed which causes this error. However, when I tried to install tensorflow in cmd it does not work as well. Any help is much appreciated.

**Note**: I am using Python 3.7 version and not using Anaconda.

Comment: Is your Python 32-bit or 64-bit? Tensorflow only supports 64-bit Python.

Comment: Python 3.7 still misses tensorflow look in the requiremenst section https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: @YuanJI the Python programme that I am using is 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed a 32-bit Python and [Tensorflow supports only 64-bit Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635450/5821988), you could:

- if you have a 64-bit system, install a 64-bit version Python
- if you have a 32-bit system, [this page](http://cudamusing.blogspot.com/2015/11/building-tensorflow-for-jetson-tk1.html) might be helpful.

Comment: I have a 64-bit system and 64-bit Python; still having issue with 'MICE'.
`AttributeError: module 'fancyimpute' has no attribute 'MICE'`

Here's my system config-
`import sys 
print(sys.executable) 
print(sys.version) 
print(sys.version_info)`



`3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`