# Tensorflow lite build for ARM9 32-bit architecture

Tags: bazel, tensorflow-lite, 32-bit, tflite, arm9

i am trying to build tensor flow wheel file using Bazel for 32-bit ARM9 architecture. but Bazel will not support for 32-bit architecture .can someone help me in building wheel file(.whl) for 32-bit architecture.

i tried to build custom tool chain but due to lack of expertise i am unable to do this.

Comment: You might get better help from people here, if you shared more details about what you are did already, sample of things you tried and error/failure messages you got and can't solve.

Comment: This [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634525/tensorflow-on-32-bit-linux) is useful for your request